# My API URL Have backslashes (\x01\x02) causing apache 400 error. How to remove those backslashes from the url

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am managing an application that gets requests through API. Some of the requests are having invalid characters.
The Request URL/API looks like:

```
/up/100.php?f=0&t=n\x01\x02&...
```

These `\x01\x02` causing Apache2 to throw 400 errors.
I can't change/alter the URL. I need to fix my apache to accept and process that URL. I tried mod_rewrite but couldn't found the correct one.

Any Help?

***Update and Solution***

Now, I found that the request is really a malfunctioned URL. So, what I did to solve the problem? I've created a custom error handling page to sanitize the URL and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)\\x01\\x02(.*)
RewriteRule ^up\.php$ /$0?%1%2 [R,L]
```

The double backslash in the *CondPattern* is necessary to match a single backslash in the query string, since the backslash is used as the escape character in PCRE regex.

The `%1` and `%2` backreferences match the characters either side of the sequence you want to remove. `$0` is just a backreference to the matched URL-path (saves repetition).

HOWEVER, a request of the form `/up.php?f=0&t=n\x01\x02&...` would not ordinarily trigger a 400 response. The character sequence `\x01\x02` in the URL is just a literal character sequence: `\`, `x`, `0`, `1`, etc. (it's not an encoded character in this context).

So, if you are getting a 400 response, it's possible that something else (a mod_security rule perhaps?) is triggering this response - which maybe out of your control?

Comment: I've tried the rewrite rule, Didn't remove the characters.
Additionally I also temporarily disabled mod_rewrite, also failed. It's still getting an error.

My Actual URL is like: /up/100.php?f=0&d=100&s=1&t=n\x01\x02&c=120

Comment: How did you "temporarily _disable_ mod_rewrite"? Do you have access to the server config? Is mod_security (and/or similar) enabled on your server? Do you have other directives in `.htaccess`? Any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Directives in the server config? Note that if this 400 response is triggered by something like mod_security then the only way to resolve this would be to remove the mod_security rule or disable mod_security altogether.

Comment: Try creating a simple redirect eg. `RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/ [R,L]` at the very top - does this do anything when requesting the problematic URL? If not, then the response is being triggered early by the server.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Yes, I have access to the server, It's a VPS. and Yes, My other rewrite rules work perfectly.

Now, I found that the request is really a malfunctioned URL. So, what I did to solve the problem? I've created a custom error handling page to sanitize the URL and make it work.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the feedback. "My _other_ rewrite rules work perfectly" - The point of testing the specific directive/redirect I mentioned, was that if that redirect occurred when requesting the _malformed_ URL then it must be possible to trap the "malformed" request and redirect using mod_rewrite (similar to posted above). Is the actual _malformed_ URL different to the URL you posted above?

Comment: Creating a custom 400 error document is another solution - you should add that as an answer (and later accept it) to help other readers, rather than editing your question with the solution. Unless you post an "answer" then the question still appears as _unanswered_ in search.